# Tensorflow DNNClassifier return wrong prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow, deep-learning

I try to make a sentence classifier using tensorflow as in the example of the official site [tf.contrib.learn Quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/tflearn/index.html) but using my own data, first I convert all my data (which are strings of varying lengths) to ids through the use of dictionaries and so transform each sentence in an array of integers.

Each record for training has its own assigned label.

The problem is that predictions are not exact, only some, but others even when the input is equal to a record of the training base the result is wrong.
My code looks something like this:

```
def launchModelData(values, labels, sample, actionClasses):

    #Tensor for trainig data
    v = tf.Variable(values)
    l = tf.Variable(labels)

    #Data Sample
    s = tf.Variable(sample)

    # Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
    classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=actionClasses)

    # Add an op to initialize the variables.
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    # Later, when launching the model
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Run the init operation.
        sess.run(init_op)

        # Fit model.
        classifier.fit(x=v.eval(), y=l.eval(), steps=200)

        # Classify one new sample.
        new_sample = np.array(s.eval(), dtype=int)
        y = classifier.predict(new_sample)
        print ('Predictions: {}'.format(str(y)))

    return y
```

Values and classes axample:

```
[0 1] 0  
[0 2] 0  
[0 4] 0  
[7 8] 1  
[7 9] 1  
[ 7 13] 1  
[14 15] 2  
[14 16] 2  
[14 18] 2  
[20 21] 3  
[26 27] 5  
[29 27] 5  
[31 32] 5  
...
```

I'm new to tensorflow so I try to make it less complex possible, any help will be welcome.

**EDIT**
My actual training data is [this.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3uEZ76zDg_wNXJnT3g5c0lWWjQ)

I try it with 8 classes and the predictions were fine, so maybe i need a bigger corpus, i will try and show my outputs in a new edit.

**EDIT2**

Now i use a composition of five layer [n,2n,4n,8n,16n] where n = Classes  and steps = 20000, this reduce the loss and  increase the accuracy really well but again it just work with a few targets (10 aprox) with a bigger amount the predictions become wrong.

Comment: Firstly, neural networks _do not_ store a snapshot of the training data. So you should not expect that the trained network will output correct labels for training data even. Such issues usually arise because of insufficient training data. Did you try using a larger training set? Please share a link to your training set if you need further help.

Comment: [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3uEZ76zDg_wNXJnT3g5c0lWWjQ) This is my data, do you think i need more for this case? I try the same code with a smaller set something like 60 samples (values) and 8 classes (targets). And the prediction is good, so i was thinking than maybe  i need more data when there is more classes (targets). Thanks for the help!

Comment: The input is just two words?

Comment: In this case yes, I change the process to compare the sentence with other sentences of the same length, so in this example i reduced that, now i can train the model whit same size arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all i made some changes in the code but there was no progress at all, so i change the parameters for the DNN Classifier and increase the size of my corpus and it works.

At the end this was my parameters aprox:
-Steps = 25000+
-Layers = [n/2,n,n*2,n*4,n*8]
* n = number classes
-Corpus size = 30000 samples
-Number classes= 40

So doing this the loss gets equal to 0.0945... and accuracy = 0.896..., dont know if doing this changes could help somebody but it does for me.

Answer (score 0):

Estimator in tf.learn responsible to create session and graph. It gets the input tensors via input_fn. Every fit/evaluate/predict will create a new session and graph. Code should look similar to following:

```
# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
my_feature = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('my_feature')
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=[my_feature], hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=actionClasses)

def _my_train_data():
  return {'my_feature': tf.constant(values), tf.constant(labels)

classifier.fit(input_fn=_my_train_data, steps=200)

# Classify one new sample.
def _my_predict_data():
  return {'my_feature': tf.Constant(s)
y = classifier.predict(input_fn=_my_predict_data)
print ('Predictions: {}'.format(str(y)))

return y
```

Comment: hmm I do not understand at all the line `return {'my_feature': tf.constant(values), tf.constant(labels)}` because i try to use some of you code but the next line give me an error: need more than 1 value to unpack
in `classifier.fit(input_fn=_my_train_data, steps=200)`. By the way thanks for the help.

Comment: I change it to  `return {'my_feature': tf.constant(values)}, tf.constant(labels)`  but the next line give me an error: `Cannot reshape a tensor with 250 elements to shape [125, 1]`.